# Actualizar fecha y hora en la web automáticamente sin necesidad de recargar la página

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

```
<?php
     date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");
     echo date("F j, Y, g:i a");
?>
```

¿Como hago para que eso se actualize de manera automatica?. No quiero recargar la pagina y me han dicho que utilize ajax pero la verdad apenas estoy aprendiendo entonces se me hace complejo saber que hacer, he mirado videos y le he pedido ayuda al profesor pero tampoco sabe jaja ¿Me podrian ayuda, por favor.

Comment: Quizá te conviene poner algo en JavaScript o colocar un iframe. Dependerá de la necesidad de ver en tiempo real el día y hora.

Comment: Si lo haces con Ajax, no recargarás la página pero estarás enviando solicitudes innecesarias al servidor, una por segundo si quieres que se actualice segundo a segundo. Es preferible pintar inicialmente la hora marcada desde PHP, pero luego que sea Javascript del lado del cliente el que vaya refrescando la hora cada segundo. Es muy sencillo, encontrarás multitud de ejemplos. Y muy mal por el profesor ;)

Comment: @AleBuo gracias brother:3 encontre una manera mas facil de hacerlo, solo usando php pero te lo agradezco!

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP gracias brother:3 encontre una manera mas facil de hacerlo, solo usando php ya que el profe me dijo que no me complicara tanto jaja, de igualmanera gracias:3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esto para tu `.php`

```
 <?php
 // nos aseguramos de que pidan la fecha por metodo POST.
 if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'date'){
   date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");
   $date = date("F j, Y, g:i a");
   // enviar en formato Json.
   echo json_encode(['date' => $date]);
 }
 ?>
```

esto para tu `.html` y `.js`

```js
function getDate(){
  $.ajax({
      url:"api.php",//la url del archivo php que procesará la peticion.
      method:"POST",//el metodo por el que se envía.
      dataType: "json",// el tipo de datos que se envía y se espera retorne.
      data: {action:'date'},//los parametros de la petición que serán procesados por el php.
      success:function(response){//en caso de que sea satisfactorio ejecutamos una función, que contendra la respuesta envíada desde el php
       $('#actualDate').text(response.date);// lo mostramos en el html.
      }
   });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(getDate(), 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Aqui vamos a mostrar la fecha. --->
<p id="actualDate"></p>
```

Comment: Gracias a todos por la ayuda, lamento no darles las gracias antes:/ mil disculpas.